# Something like WebPart for MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, web-parts

I find opensource project or library when I find implementation something like WebPart.
I thanks for any project when I can see implementation something like WebPart.

Of course implementation must be in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Mvc uses web parts look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106629/using-webparts-in-an-mvc-application) or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/16/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-webpart-framework.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web Parts are still available in MVC, as it's a set of ASP.NET ...

you will have all controls and all properties that you had before.